# Merging two vector layers with different granularity

Tags: qgis, merge, mergeshapes

I am a beginner at QGIS.

I have two vector layers. One represents country boundaries for the whole world. The other one represents region boundaries, but only for OECD countries.

I would like to create a unique layer that would use country boundaries for non-OECD members and region boundaries for OECD members.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Do your vectors contain separate rows for each country/region boundary? If so you should be able to do this easily with a bit of editing. If your vector just contains a single feature then it may be more difficult. Could you upload a couple of screenshots please.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it using the "Merge vector layers" tool. I am not sure the exact name of the menu because my software is in French.

With that command, I just had to select the two layers I wanted to merge and I was done. It did mess some attributes that were not in common between my two files (e.g. one layer did not have "Population" attribute, all entities in that layer received the value 2), but it does not matter because these are not attribute I will use so I can discard them.